# MySQL LIKE query - return just the matched substring in SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, extract

Is there a way to return from MySQL LIKE query the matched full substring. What I mean

`` SELECT `title` FROM `search_index` WHERE (`title` LIKE '%inno%') ``
which returns bunch of matched records.

and the title would look like `Innovative Technology`

than the extracted title just returns the  `Innovative` match ?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's LIKE operator isn't really suitable to detect an exact single word inside a string. But REGEXP, which supports regular expressions, can handle this. Consider the following query:

```
SELECT title FROM search_index WHERE title REGEXP '[[:<:]]inno[[:>:]]';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
select regexp_substr('Innovative Technology', '[a-zA-Z]*inno[a-zA-Z]*')
```